# Ubuntu not detecting microphone on new headphones

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

Huawei FreeBuds 3i

Ubuntu 20.04

KDE Desktop

So, I have searched all around but nothing has solved my problem that Ubuntu simply will not detect the mic on my headphones. They earphones connect and sound works great, but I can't get the mic detected.

I have tried blueman and pipewire (probably incorrectly) but couldn't get either to work. I have no idea how to this stuff works on Linux, so I am at a complete loss. I am not even sure how to check what the problem is. If anybody can help to get my mic detected I would appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, probably incorrect. In order to use the microphone you need to select the "hands-free" profile - HFP - instead of the default HiFi Stereo profile (A2DP). Then it may or may not work as intended but the troubleshooting is done from that point on and it doesn't entail installing random stuff.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I have 0 experience or knowledge about this stuff.

Comment: How *would* you go about doing it is the question.... Now it's unclear what was installed an how. Usually after pairing and connecting it defaults to the most used profile A2DP. It can be changed at system settings > sound (or from the main menu with a certain Gnome extension is installed) where a dropdown menu should show the other option, HFP.